# c++ clr host can execute c# but not vb.net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, clr

I have this code that can execute c# assembly from unmanaged c++ program with clr run time host 
it work well with c# but with vb.net it doesn't work although both languages are compiled to il code and run over .net framework

this is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <metahost.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "MSCorEE.lib")

#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb" 
raw_interfaces_only \
high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")     \
rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")
using namespace mscorlib;



unsigned char rawData[] = {
// .net exe bytes
};

#define RAW_ASSEMBLY_LENGTH sizeof(rawData);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ICLRMetaHost* pMetaHost = NULL;

HRESULT hr;

/* Get ICLRMetaHost instance */

hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, 
(VOID**)&pMetaHost);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] CLRCreateInstance(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] CLRCreateInstance(...) succeeded\n");

ICLRRuntimeInfo* pRuntimeInfo = NULL;

/* Get ICLRRuntimeInfo instance */

hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v2.0.50727", IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, 
(VOID**)&pRuntimeInfo);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pMetaHost->GetRuntime(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pMetaHost->GetRuntime(...) succeeded\n");

BOOL bLoadable;

/* Check if the specified runtime can be loaded */

hr = pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&bLoadable);

if(FAILED(hr) || !bLoadable)
{
    printf("[!] pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(...) succeeded\n");

ICorRuntimeHost* pRuntimeHost = NULL;

/* Get ICorRuntimeHost instance */

hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_ICorRuntimeHost, 
(VOID**)&pRuntimeHost);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(...) succeeded\n");

/* Start the CLR */

hr = pRuntimeHost->Start();

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pRuntimeHost->Start() failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pRuntimeHost->Start() succeeded\n");

IUnknownPtr pAppDomainThunk = NULL;

hr = pRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain(&pAppDomainThunk);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain(...) succeeded\n");

_AppDomainPtr pDefaultAppDomain = NULL;

/* Equivalent of System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain in C# */

hr = pAppDomainThunk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(_AppDomain), (VOID**) 
&pDefaultAppDomain);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pAppDomainThunk->QueryInterface(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pAppDomainThunk->QueryInterface(...) succeeded\n");

_AssemblyPtr pAssembly = NULL;

SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];

rgsabound[0].cElements = RAW_ASSEMBLY_LENGTH;

rgsabound[0].lLbound   = 0;

SAFEARRAY* pSafeArray  = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound);

void* pvData = NULL;

hr = SafeArrayAccessData(pSafeArray, &pvData);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] SafeArrayAccessData(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] SafeArrayAccessData(...) succeeded\n");

memcpy(pvData, rawData, RAW_ASSEMBLY_LENGTH);

hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(pSafeArray);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] SafeArrayUnaccessData(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] SafeArrayUnaccessData(...) succeeded\n");

/* Equivalent of System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(byte[] rawAssembly) */

hr = pDefaultAppDomain->Load_3(pSafeArray, &pAssembly);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pDefaultAppDomain->Load_3(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pDefaultAppDomain->Load_3(...) succeeded\n");

_MethodInfoPtr pMethodInfo = NULL;

/* Assembly.EntryPoint Property */

hr = pAssembly->get_EntryPoint(&pMethodInfo);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pAssembly->get_EntryPoint(...) failed\n");

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pAssembly->get_EntryPoint(...) succeeded\n");

VARIANT retVal;
ZeroMemory(&retVal, sizeof(VARIANT));

VARIANT obj;
ZeroMemory(&obj, sizeof(VARIANT));
obj.vt = VT_NULL;

//TODO! Change cElement to the number of Main arguments
SAFEARRAY *psaStaticMethodArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);

/* EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[0]) */

hr = pMethodInfo->Invoke_3(obj, psaStaticMethodArgs, &retVal); // fails here

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("[!] pMethodInfo->Invoke_3(...) failed, hr = %X\n", hr);

    getchar();

    return -1;
}

printf("[+] pMethodInfo->Invoke_3(...) succeeded\n");

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

I get this when I use vb bytes :

[!] pMethodInfo->Invoke_3(...) failed, hr = 80131604

I've tried using both .net framework versions v4 and v2 and changed the number of arguments but no effect

Comment: I've done similar things before, and I too had a problem with VB.NET assemblies. I think it's due to the odd application structure VB.NET creates when using automatically generated application code, i.e. the _Application Framework_. What kind of assembly is it you're trying to run? WinForms app? Console? WPF? Other? -- If you're using WinForms try declaring your own entry point by going into the VB.NET project's settings and disabling `Enable Application Framework`.

Comment: can you explain more about project settings as I am not familar with vb but I need to run som .net assembly from c++ code , and I'm tried with WinForms app and an app that I don't have the source code of it

Comment: Oh, so it isn't your own VB.NET assembly? In that case you cannot change anything. It only works of you have access to the VB.NET source code.

Comment: It is very, very implausible that this has anything to do with the language.  You need to always assume that the code you invoke might not use try/catch or properly uses the AppDomain.UnhandledException event to report unhandled exceptions.  In which case you get to see them.  Using IErrorInfo is pretty important to get better exception info.  0x80131604 is TargetInvocationException, that's a bummer.  Change the debugger type from Auto to Mixed so you can see the managed code throwing exceptions.

Comment: I converted the WinForms app to ConsoleApp and it worked , I think there is some thing in vb WinForms app Main function throws an exception as I found the description of hresult error as follows :  
Uncaught exception thrown by method called through Reflection

Comment: Hmm, Main() certainly exists but is just auto-generated in a vb.net assembly.  Easy to see with a decompiler, navigate to the projname.My.MyApplication class.  The OP correctly uses pAssembly->get_EntryPoint() to find it.

Comment: @HansPassant : Oh? Then I've really missed something during my previous research :). I tried to do the exact same thing as the OP a year or two ago, but I never got a VB.NET WinForms app to work.

Comment: this code in c# works well , I'll try to get similar in c++ :                    Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(data);
            exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);

Comment: edit : the code above didn't work but this did : Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(data);
            String[] ps = { "dsfds" };
            object[] pss = { ps };
            exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, pss);                                               the problem is that you should specify an array of objects of strings to be a parameter , thus the solution is to intialize SAFEARRAY *psaStaticMethodArgs to get the same result in c#

Comment: It worked now in c++